# Can't get first child selector to work

Tags: css

I am aware of the irony of a (mediocre) website freelancer not being able to get some CSS to work on his own site...

However, wondering if you'd help me with this, as I am no expert on CSS.

On [this webpage](https://websitetechnology.com.au/blog/project/white-wreath-association/), Wordpress has injected a dodgy image which is not contained in the post.

[image]

I want to hide it with CSS.

I have tried the following CSS:

```
body.postid-62 article p:first-child img {display: none;}
```

However, this CSS is not being applied to the image when I view the problem image in Google Code Inspector.

If I add it as a new style in Code Inspector, the image remains.

Can you determine the correct CSS to hide the image please?

Thanks.

Comment: Although removing the image is of course the best solution, if you need a quick hack I'd use `img[src=""] { display:none; }`. Covers more cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `p` is just not the first element of it's parent, there is an `h2` before it. Use `:first-of-type` instead:

```
body.postid-62 article p:first-of-type img {display: none;}
```

Comment: Oh, I thought first element meant it was the first `p` element of its parent. Thanks.

Comment: @Steve unfortunately the name is a little misleading indeed

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
.main.single p>img {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can select your image checking the alt tag it.

The following example, hides your image.

```
img[alt*="White Wreath Association"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Here your HTML just for reference:

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4051" src="https://websitetechnology.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/whitewreath.jpg" alt="White Wreath Association" width="1280" height="888" srcset="https://websitetechnology.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/whitewreath-768x532.jpg 768w, https://websitetechnology.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/whitewreath-610x423.jpg 610w, https://websitetechnology.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/whitewreath.jpg 1280w" sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px">
```